# Apply to all elements in the list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to compute the mean of the elements of a list.
Given a txt where I have the name and then the numbers to compute the mean:

```
Bob 5 6 9 10 5
Alice 10 3 5 6 8
Kate 2 4
```

I use the words function to get a list of the input file so I can process it.

I'm trying to construct a list of tuples to compute then the mean with the function composeList, but I only get the first element:

```
[("Bob",[5.0,6.0,9.0,10.0,5.0])]
```

I don't know how to get the list of tuples and then calculate the mean, to get

[("Bob", 7.0), ("Alice", 6.5), "Kate", 7.75)]

Here is what I have so far:

```
import qualified Data.Text    as Text
import qualified Data.Text.IO as Text
import Data.String



readLines :: FilePath -> IO [String]
readLines = fmap lines . readFile 

calculateMean :: [Double] -> Double
calculateMean [] = 0
calculateMean (a) = sum a / fromIntegral(length a)


--calculateMeanList :: [String] -> (String,[Double])
--calculateMeanList (a) = (head $ words $ head a, calculateMean $ convertNumeric $ tail $ words $ head $ a)

convertNumeric :: [String] -> [Double]
convertNumeric = map read


composeList :: [String] -> [(String, [Double])]
composeList (a) = [(head $ words $ head $ a, convertNumeric $ tail $ words $ head $ a)]


main = do
    
    ls <- readLines "puntuaciones.txt"
    
  
    print $ words $ head $ ls

    print $ composeList ls
```

Comment: First write a function that can turn a single pair `("Bob",[5.0,6.0,9.0,10.0,5.0])` into the wanted `("Bob",7.0)`. Something like `foo (name, values) = (... , ...)` should do. Then `map` it over the list-of-pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only take the words of the `head`, so of course you only get the first element. You should be mapping the `words` function across the lines:

```hs
import qualified Data.Text    as Text
import qualified Data.Text.IO as Text
import Data.String

readLines :: FilePath -> IO [String]
readLines = fmap lines . readFile

calculateMean :: [Double] -> Double
calculateMean [] = 0
calculateMean (a) = sum a / fromIntegral(length a)

convertNumeric :: [String] -> [Double]
convertNumeric = map read


composeList :: [String] -> [(String, [Double])]
-- could be written with a map but list comprehension is cleaner
composeList a = [(head curWords, convertNumeric $ tail curWords) | curWords <- map words a]

main = do
    ls <- readLines "puntuaciones.txt"
    let composed = composeList ls
    print composed
    -- this could also be written with a list comprehension
    -- [(a, calculateMean b) | (a, b) <- composed]
    print $ map (\(a, b) -> (a, calculateMean b)) composed
```

Comment: OK, I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks! I was trying to create a function for that, and replace the lambda function you created, but guess I'm doing it wrong too: ```calculateMeanList2 :: (String,[Double]) -> (String, Double)
calculateMeanList2 (a, b) = map (\l -> ((a, calculateMean b) l))
```

Comment: Also, your lambda is wrong because you need to maintain the first element of the tuple outside the map, then just take the mean of the list, so it would look like `calculateMeanList2 (a, b) = (a, calculateMean b)`

Comment: But is there a way to call the map on that function calculateMeanList2? I'm trying to encapsulate all that in the function.

Comment: `calculateMeanList2` simply works on a tuple. You can then just `map calculateMeanList2 composed` to modify the full list.